# How would I run an .sh file using Java and get its output?

Tags: java, linux, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java code to execute a .sh file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464797/java-code-to-execute-a-sh-file)

I write the code in a .sh file with one parameter in `/root/new_scripts/setpermission.sh` and run it: `setpermission.sh` contains:

```
chmod 777 $1
```

It executed successfully from linux console by typing /root/new_scripts/setpermission.sh location . But when i tried to run it using java code using:
Java full code:

```
String fileLocation = BASE_DIR + domain + SUB_DIR_CAKE + fileName;
    File newFile = new File(fileLocation);
    System.out.println("Permission file location: " + fileLocation);
    if(newFile.exists()) {
        String command;
        String[] commandArray;
        command = "/root/new_scripts/setpermission.sh";
        File commandFile = new File(command);
        if(commandFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nFILE EXISTS");
        } else {
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nFILE NOT EXISTS");
        }
        commandArray = new String[]{"/bin/sh", command, newFile.toString()};
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandArray);
            return "HERE OK";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "file not exists";
    }
```

and it returns `HERE OK`

Comment: Do you get the "execution error" or is just nothing happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
            String command;
            String[] commandArray;


            command = "./new_scripts/setpermission.sh";
            commandArray = new String[]{"/bin/sh", command, fileLocation, permission};
          try {

              Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandArray);

         } catch (Exception e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Hey, you need to know that root is one of my folder as new_scripts. Anth its not working for me, any suggestion please?

Comment: new_scripts is your working directory right then you need to give in command only "./setpermission.sh" or "setpermission.sh"

Comment: No man, my working directory is elsewhere, any place, not specified.

Comment: then where u put your sh file??? give that whole path from root

Comment: String command;
            String[] commandArray;
            command = "/root/new_scripts/setpermission.sh";
            commandArray = new String[]{"/bin/sh", command, fileLocation, permission};
            try {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandArray);
                return "HERE OK";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.getMessage();
            }

Comment: In root directory there is a folder named root, root folder contains another folder new_scripts and setpermission.sh in new_scripts folder.

Comment: have you give all permission to setpermission.sh file ?

Comment: try this in console "chmod 777 setpermission.sh" then try to run through java code

Comment: then it should work. put that sh file in working directory and if it is work then there is some prob in your path if not then you should check your sh file once again

Comment: sh file is not in my working directory, is that my problem?

Comment: no this is not the problem. i just say to ensure that your sh file is correct because you are doing right but it doesn't work then there should be some other problem

Comment: sh file is correct. when i run that sh file using command /root/new_scripts/setpermission.sh filename 777, it is working fine, but when tried to run through java code, it didnt work.

Comment: it work fine in my system i am unable to catch what have you done wrong.please check sh file path once again using pwd command

Comment: IN SH FILE the code is chmod 777 $1 and in java file http://codepad.org/oOkjgAav and print 'FILE EXISTS' and return 'HERE OK', no exception.

Comment: have you check your fileLocation path ? there is no error in your code and it work in my system i have checked it.

Comment: it will give Exception only if it unable to run that sh file if your give wrong target file location then it won't give exception

Comment: Please see my full java code http://codepad.org/Wlhsz6ny, fileLocation is ok.

Comment: how did you check this is not working. commandArray = new String[]{"/bin/sh", command, "/home/virtual/karen3.webalive.com.au/app/webroot/robots.txt"}; in fileLocation better you give newFile.toString()

Comment: I have tried both way but they are not responding anyhow. What can I now at this moment? Where is my problem? In sh file or java code?

Comment: hey dude, don't be frustrated your both code is correct.check it after a sort break i am sure that you will definitely fix it.

Comment: You need to know that in /bin folder, there is a sh shorcut, not sh file.

Comment: hey that "sh" shortcut need to run that "setpermission.sh" file

Comment: Could be time for a chat room for this?

Comment: command = "/root/new_scripts/setpermission.sh " + fileLocation + " " + permission;            
            try {
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process process = runtime.exec(command);
                return "true";
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return "false";
            }

Answer (score 3):

Please post the Java code that you're using to attempt this.  However, by making a few assumptions, you probably need to find and use the fully-qualified path to "sh", as the Java ProcessBuilder won't make use of a set "PATH" environment variable.

Comment: got it? i have added java code.

Comment: So his answer is 100% correct ... you need to provide the full path to `sh`

Comment: ./root/new_scripts/setpermission.sh provides full path, but not working.

Comment: Is your . in "./root" literal, or a typo?  If literal, this won't work either.  You would need an absolute, full path to the script.  (Symbolic links would be o.k.)

Comment: How can i know that ./root is literal or type? plase do me a favour.

Comment: I was asking if you had a typo - and since it matches what's now in your edit, I'm assuming it's not a typo.  That said, you now have 2 problems:  You need to specify the full path to "chmod", as well as to your .sh script.  ("./root/..." is not an absolute path.)  A proper absolute path will begin with "/".

Comment: String command = "sh /root/new_scripts/setpermission.sh " + fileLocation + " " + permission;

Comment: You need to edit your original question to get it "in order".  Your 2 code blocks, along to your comments to this answer are all contradicting themselves.  Are you trying to call "sh" or "chmod"?  Either way, you need to call it with its fully-qualified path, e.g. /bin/sh or /bin/chmod .

Comment: Ok, i am calling a .sh file using java code described some times ago and in that .sh file it set permission to a file using chmod.

Comment: @user1044804 What Ziesemer is trying to say is that you need to change `sh` at the beginning of your command to `/bin/sh`.

Comment: String command = "/bin/sh /root/new_scripts/setpermission.sh /home/a.txt 777";
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); Not working.